# Crystal report in web api is not working in azure server

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, crystal-reports

Hi i am using crystal report to create a report and send the report to a particular email address.It was working correctly in my local machine,but when i uploaded in azure it is showing me the following error.

Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

Comment: I have already tried what the below link is suggested to me.
[link](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/crystal-reports-on-azure-how-to.html)

Answer (score 1):

need to instal additional file on windows azure server.